# Routes for web api inside folder

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

Currently i am using a web api for my asp.net application. I have put controller inside a folder called  "Reports". The content of webApiConfig is following:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

When i try to access using this, the result shows "Not found". If i put the api diresctly in my project, it works.
I am a bit aware about areas in MVC, but as it is normal asp .net, i am not sure how to handle this problem.
Any help will br greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the url you try to access? What is your contorller/action name?

Comment: I have used api/Reports/ReportController/LogReports

Answer (score -1):

It's working. I just needed to add Folder name between api & controller as below

```
api/<foldername>/{Controllername}/{actionmethod}/{id}
```

I am using following url now.

```
api/Reports/ReportController/LogReports
```